# Overriding save() method in Model. How to do this correctly?

Tags: django

I try overriding save() method in Model. How to do this correctly?

```
import Image
from tesseract import image_to_string

class FileModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    base_file = models.FileField(upload_to="files")
    after_file = models.FileField(upload_to="file_ocr", blank=True, null=True)

   def save(self):
       after_file = image_to_string(Image.open('base_file'), lang='en')
       after_file.save()
       super(FileModel, self).save()
```

If `base_file` is created I need use `image_to_string()` method and save result like `after_file`.

Comment: only when created or every time it's saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    creating = self.pk is None
    super(FileModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if creating:
        self.after_file = image_to_string(Image.open('base_file'), lang='en')
        self.after_file.save()
```

or with signals:

```
from django.db.models import signals
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(signals.post_save, sender=FileModel)
def create_file(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.after_file = image_to_string(Image.open('base_file'), lang='en')
        instance.after_file.save()
```

Comment: @dev_fight You can obtain the file path from the field, the field name is not the file name. I don't have experience working with files yet, but I think it should be one of the following: `Image.open(self.base_file) or Image.open(self.base_file.file) or Image.open(self.base_file.url)`.